# How to format the output of logs in the console?(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging)

Tags: c#, logging, console

I make logs output like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
                                             .AddConsole();

        ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

        logger.LogInformation(
          "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

And I receive messages:

> info: ConsoleLogging.Program[0]
>
> This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.

But I would like so:

> info: This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.

How to format the output of logs in the console?
I use the libraries Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same thing.

I started out by creating a class called `SimpleConsoleLogger` that inherits from `ConsoleLogger` so that I could override the `WriteMessage()` method, but the code in the original method relies on some private internal structs and fields, and I didn't want to write the whole method from scratch.

I ended up creating my own `SimpleConsoleLogger` class [based off the source code for ConsoleLogger.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console) where I could remove the following lines in `WriteMessage()` in the category and event id section:

```
logBuilder.Append(logName);
logBuilder.Append("[");
logBuilder.Append(eventId);
logBuilder.AppendLine("]");
```

...and the following line in the message section:

```
logBuilder.Append(_messagePadding);
```

I then had to create a `SimpleConsoleLoggerProvider` class based on `ConsoleLoggerProvider`, where I substituted my `SimpleConsoleLogger` class in the code, and did the same with `ConsoleLoggerExtensions` in order to create `SimpleConsoleLoggerExtensions`, so that I may wire my logger into the factory as follows:

```
_loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddSimpleConsole();
```

This is not the most simple solution, so the class name is a bit of a misnomer, but it works.

[image: Solution Code in Action]