# Creating ConsoleLogger directly astonishingly doesn't work

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't just work?  This feels astonishing to me.  If this is not a viable usage, I would say that this is a design smell.  I should either be not permitted to do this by the API's design, or I would expect a useful error.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var l = new ConsoleLogger("test", (s, ll) => true, true);
        l.WriteMessage(LogLevel.Critical, "test", 0, "hello world", null);
    }
```

This implementation outputs literally nothing.  Why? I don't feel like I should have to use the DependencyInjection and service location mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because of the fire and forget (`Task.Factory.StartNew`) implementation. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/2eb498eb7395a008e0495ae19dbe1d7f05f7d3e8/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/Internal/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs#L22). (In other words, the code doesn't wait for the message to be printed.)

If you do this:

```
var l = new ConsoleLogger("test", (s, ll) => true, true);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   l.WriteMessage(LogLevel.Critical, "test", 0, "hello world", null);
}
```

it works fine and the messages are being printed.

If you need to do the console logging synchronously, I suggest you implement your [own console logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015660/how-to-format-the-output-of-logs-in-the-consolemicrosoft-extensions-logging) where you await the logging operation.